# Ember.js - can't get or set model property

Tags: ember.js

I have an Ember.js model with fixtures that looks like this:

```
App.Category = DS.Model.extend({
    category: attr('string'),
    friendly: attr('string'),
    iconUrl: attr('string'),
    isPrimary: attr('bool'),
    isSecondary: attr('bool'),
    isTertiaryOne: attr('bool'),
    isTertiaryTwo: attr('bool')
});

App.Category.reopenClass({
    FIXTURES: [
        {
            id: 1,
            category: 'recommended',
            friendly: 'recommended for you',
            iconUrl: 'image1.png',
            isPrimary: true,
            isSecondary: false,
            isTertiaryOne: false,
            isTertiaryTwo: false
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            category: 'recent',
            friendly: 'recently viewed',
            iconUrl: 'image2.png',
            isPrimary: false,
            isSecondary: true,
            isTertiaryOne: false,
            isTertiaryTwo: false
        }
    ]
});
```

All I want to do is retrieve a property value from a specific model, and set it to a new value in an action in my controller:

```
App.CategoryController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({    
    actions: {
        tileClick: function (selectedCategory) {
            var cat = this.store.find('category', { category: selectedCategory });
            console.log(cat.get('isPrimary'));
            cat.set('isPrimary', true);
        }
    }
});
```

The Emberjs website guides say that all I have to do to set a value is :

```
var tyrion = this.store.find('person', 1);
// ...after the record has loaded
tyrion.set('firstName', "Yollo");
```

but it just isn't working.

The variable 'cat' exists, and if I drill down deep enough into the object in the console, I can see the properties I want, so I know the correct model is being selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `store.find` method returns you a promise, so you have to (as you wrote) wait till it's loaded.

You should read about promises more, but what you could do now is:

```
var cat = this.store.find('category', {
  category: selectedCategory
}).then(function(categories) {
  categories.forEach(function(category) {
    category.set('isPrimary', true);
  });
});
```

Note that if you're using query param (`find` with an object is effectively `findQuery`), you get the list of models, not a specific model, even if only one was found.